# Operate on Julia ranges to go from physical units to array indices

Tags: python, julia, slice

I'm trying to come up with a way to operate on Julia ranges so that they be specified in certain units and then translated into indices. To explain better, please consider the example below:

```
julia> Δx = 150
150

julia> x = collect(0:Δx:1000)
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
   0
 150
 300
 450
 600
 750
 900

julia> y = @. x^2 + 50
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
     50
  22550
  90050
 202550
 360050
 562550
 810050
```

Say I want to get every value that between `x`s 100 and 500. If I know the corresponding indices I can get a chunk of the array based on the indices easily by using a range:

```
julia> index_chunk = 2:4
2:4

julia> y[index_chunk]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  22550
  90050
 202550
```

However, I'd like to be able to get the same result but creating an index based on the units. Something like

```
julia> phys_chunk = 100:500
100:500

julia> y[phys_chunk/Δx]
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 7-element Array{Int64,1} at index [0.6666666666666666:0.006666666666666667:3.3333333333333335]
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_boundserror(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Tuple{StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}) at ./abstractarray.jl:541
 [2] checkbounds at ./abstractarray.jl:506 [inlined]
 [3] _getindex at ./multidimensional.jl:742 [inlined]
 [4] getindex(::Array{Int64,1}, ::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}) at ./abstractarray.jl:1060
 [5] top-level scope at REPL[24]:1
```

But of course, that fails. I've tried a couple other things along the same lines (like `phys_chunk//Δx`), but I haven't had any luck. Is it possible to do what I want to do?

PS: For those who are familiar with Python, I'm trying to recreate the behavior of `xarray`'s `.sel()` method of slicing:

```py
In [4]: da = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [("x", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])])

In [5]: da
Out[5]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5)>
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4

In [6]: da.sel(x=slice(0.9, 3.1))
Out[6]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3)>
array([2, 3, 4])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2 3
```

Comment: I don't really understand your Python example, or, in fact, exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to create integers, you should use `div` instead of `/` or `//`: so `div.(phys_chunk, Δx)`, note the dot. This will, however, *not* create the indices you are looking for, I think, but it shows how to do integer division.

Answer (score 2):

What about logical indexing?

```
julia> y[100 .< x .< 500]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  22550
  90050
 202550
```

---

Edit: Adding a bit of substance using [DimensionalData.jl](https://github.com/rafaqz/DimensionalData.jl) in light of the comments. (Note I just tried this package out, so there might be better ways to use it.)

Let me create a 2D `DimArray` called `V`, which has the same `x` dimension as your original-post example, but now also has a 2nd dimension that I call `y`:

```
julia> using DimensionalData

julia> Δx = 150
150

julia> x = 0:Δx:1000 # your x (no need to collect it)
0:150:900

julia> y = -500:100:500 # let's make the example 2D (now y is the 2nd dim)
-500:100:500

julia> V = DimArray(x.^2 .+ 2 .* y', (X(x), Y(y))) # V is a 2D DimArray
DimArray (named ) with dimensions:
 X: 0:150:900 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
 Y: -500:100:500 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
and data: 7×11 Matrix{Int64}
  -1000    -800    -600    -400    -200  …     400     600     800    1000
  21500   21700   21900   22100   22300      22900   23100   23300   23500
  89000   89200   89400   89600   89800      90400   90600   90800   91000
 201500  201700  201900  202100  202300     202900  203100  203300  203500
 359000  359200  359400  359600  359800     360400  360600  360800  361000
 561500  561700  561900  562100  562300  …  562900  563100  563300  563500
 809000  809200  809400  809600  809800     810400  810600  810800  811000
```

Note that this `V` has the same values as your original data for `y == 0`:

```
julia> V[Y(At(0))]
DimArray (named ) with dimensions:
 X: 0:150:900 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
and referenced dimensions:
 Y: 0 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
and data: 7-element Vector{Int64}
[0, 22500, 90000, 202500, 360000, 562500, 810000]
```

And I can select the values at `y=0` and for `100<x<500` that way:

```
julia> V[X(Between(100, 500)), Y(At(0))]
DimArray (named ) with dimensions:
 X: 150:150:450 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
and referenced dimensions:
 Y: 0 (Sampled: Ordered Regular Points)
and data: 3-element Vector{Int64}
[22500, 90000, 202500]
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Would that work if `y` was two or three dimensional though?

Comment: Straight yes if `x` has the same size. If `x` is a vector indexing the 2nd dimension of a 3D `y`, then yes with something like `y[:, 100 .< x .< 500, :]`.

Comment: FWIW, if you are working with spatio-temporal data, you should check packages that deal with these kinds of features, like, e.g., [DimensionalData](https://github.com/rafaqz/DimensionalData.jl)

Comment: DimensionalData is nice, but at the moment it seems to me that there are [many competing packages trying to reproduce what xarray does](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/the-fate-of-dimensionalarrays-axisarrays-in-julia-and-which-to-actually-use/33253/4) so I'm not sure if I want to commit to one of those packages just yet

Comment: Also, your approach is pretty simple, but it requires the user (which is not always myself) to figure out what array corresponds to a given dimension (in this case it's obvious it's `x`, but it might not be). This is avoided if I can somehow use a range for that

Comment: I am aware of the status of things, but you should *not* be averse to committing to a package.  Moving on to the next one if need be will not be too hard IMHO. Also, I don't think being a range vs an array is an issue here. I you mean you want an array of *indices* (not the same thing as a "range"), you could try `findall(@. 100 < x < 500)` for example.

Comment: Added a DimensionalData example to the answer.